# How can I perform the equivalent of an index match for Excel in SQL?

Tags: sql

I want to create a query that determines the highest **ShipFromCount** (when it starts with 'F' and when it starts with 'K'). Essentially, I want to determine the higher value for each case and index match the higher value to get the corresponding **ShipFrom**.

Below is a sample of a table I'm working with:

| StoreNumber | ID | ShipFrom | ShipFromCount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0001 | 01 | FA | 300 |
| 0001 | 01 | FB | 100 |
| 0001 | 01 | KA | 200 |

I want to return an output that looks like this:

| StoreNumber | ID | F_MostFreq | F_Amount | K_MostFreq | K_Amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0001 | 01 | FA | 300 | KA | 200 |

Here is the query I wrote so far, but it's not working as expected.

```
SELECT StoreNumber, ID, 
    MAX(CASE WHEN LEFT(ShipFrom, 1) = 'F' THEN ShipFrom END) AS F_MostFreq,
    MAX(CASE WHEN LEFT(ShipFrom, 1) = 'F' THEN ShipFromCount END) AS F_Amount,
    MAX(CASE WHEN LEFT(ShipFrom, 1) = 'K' THEN ShipFrom END) AS K_MostFreq,
    MAX(CASE WHEN LEFT(ShipFrom, 1) = 'K' THEN ShipFromCount END) AS K_Amount,
FROM SampleData
GROUP BY StoreNumber, ID;
```

Here's the output, which is wrong:

| StoreNumber | ID | F_MostFreq | F_Amount | K_MostFreq | K_Amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0001 | 01 | FB | 300 | KA | 200 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
with data as (
    select *, row_number() over (partition by StoreNumber, ID, left(ShipFrom, 1) order by ShipFromCount desc) as rn
    from SampleData
)
select StoreNumber, ID,
    min(ShipFrom) AS F_MostFreq,
    min(case when ShipFrom LIKE 'F%' then ShipFromCount end) AS F_Amount,
    max(ShipFrom) AS K_MostFreq,
    min(case when ShipFrom LIKE 'K%' then ShipFromCount end) AS K_Amount
from data
where rn = 1
group by StoreNumber, ID;
```

Comment: You are a gentleman and a scholar.

Answer (score 1):

The individual MAX() functions in your query are really working independently of each other, so just because you tell the query to get the MAX() of "ShipFrom", it's just looking at the "FA" and "FB" values and deciding which one of those values it thinks is the MAX (and, alphabetically, that is "FB") - independent of the "ShipFromCount" values.

You need to first establish the "StoreNumber", "ID", "ShipFrom" combination that has the highest "ShipFromCount" value, and then when you know you have the "correct" "ShipFrom" value, you can then query on the MAX() of "ShipFromCount".

Here is an example of how you can use a CTE to firstly get you the relevant StoreNumber, ID, ShipFrom combinations (that match your particular criteria), and then output the full results that you want to see.
(In reality, I'm going to guess that you've actually got many rows of data to work with, and you may want to output your results based on different StoreNumber / ID values, so you'll need to adjust the query to suit your final needs.  Hopefully this example guides you in the right direction)

```
CREATE TABLE #x (StoreNumber varchar(10), ID varchar(10), ShipFrom varchar(10), ShipFromCount smallint);
INSERT INTO #x
VALUES ('0001','01','FA',300),
('0001','01','FB',100),
('0001','01','KA',200);


-- this with output as rows per result
WITH cte AS
(
    SELECT TOP 1 StoreNumber, ID, ShipFrom
    FROM #x 
    WHERE ShipFrom LIKE 'F%'
    ORDER BY ShipFromCount DESC

    UNION

    SELECT TOP 1 StoreNumber, ID, ShipFrom
    FROM #x 
    WHERE ShipFrom LIKE 'K%'
    ORDER BY ShipFromCount DESC
)
SELECT 
    x.StoreNumber,
    x.ID,
    x.ShipFrom,
    MAX(x.ShipFromCount) AS [MaxShipFromCount]
FROM #x x
INNER JOIN cte 
ON x.StoreNumber = cte.StoreNumber
AND x.ID = cte.ID
AND x.ShipFrom = cte.ShipFrom
GROUP BY 
    x.StoreNumber,
    x.ID,
    x.ShipFrom;


-- this with output in a single row, as per your question
WITH cte AS
(
    SELECT TOP 1 StoreNumber, ID, ShipFrom
    FROM #x 
    WHERE ShipFrom LIKE 'F%'
    ORDER BY ShipFromCount DESC

    UNION

    SELECT TOP 1 StoreNumber, ID, ShipFrom
    FROM #x 
    WHERE ShipFrom LIKE 'K%'
    ORDER BY ShipFromCount DESC
)
SELECT 
    x.StoreNumber,
    x.ID,
    MAX(CASE WHEN x.ShipFrom LIKE 'F%' THEN x.ShipFrom END) AS [F_MostFreq],
    MAX(CASE WHEN x.ShipFrom LIKE 'F%' THEN x.ShipFromCount END) AS [F_Amount],
    MAX(CASE WHEN x.ShipFrom LIKE 'K%' THEN x.ShipFrom END) AS [K_MostFreq],
    MAX(CASE WHEN x.ShipFrom LIKE 'K%' THEN x.ShipFromCount END) AS [K_Amount]
FROM #x x
INNER JOIN cte 
ON x.StoreNumber = cte.StoreNumber
AND x.ID = cte.ID
AND x.ShipFrom = cte.ShipFrom
GROUP BY 
    x.StoreNumber,
    x.ID;

DROP TABLE #x;
```